# List<integer> c1=new Arraylist<integer>what type object is c1

Tags: java

In collections in java

```
List<Integer>  c1=new Arraylist<Integer>
```

Here, c1 is an object of type List which is an interface, and we can't create an object of that interface?

Can somebody explain this to me?

Answer (score 5):

The type of the variable `c1` is `List<Integer>`. That just means that the value of `c1` at any time has to either be `null`, or a reference to an object whose type implements `List`.

However, the type of the *object* that the value of `c1` refers to at execution time is `ArrayList`. (It doesn't know it was constructed as an `ArrayList<Integer>` due to type erasure.)

It's very important to distinguish between three concepts:

- Variables (such as `c1`). A variable has a type at compile time.
- References (such as the value of `c1`)
- Objects (such as the one the value of `c1` refers to). An object has a type at execution time (it doesn't exist before then).

If you can keep those three straight in your head, it makes a lot of things (like parameter passing, assignments etc) a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

An object "is" the object that it is, and all of its base classes, and all the interfaces that it and its base classes implement.